# ORACLE ORDER BY in SELECT subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I want to select a varchar field SUBJECT in a subquery, ordered by a date field DATETO. Specific: the ONE subject field of the latest entry, therefore ordered by the date field.

```
SELECT MDKAMVP.MDKAMDA_SID, 
(select SUBJECT from mdkndlst where rownum=1 and SUBJECT is not null 
order by DATETO) NAKTION, MDKAMVP.ROWID ROW_ID 
FROM SPRINGV2.MDKAMVP order by MDKAMVP.INDSTATUS
```

Error:

```
ORA-00907: Rechte Klammer fehlt
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Fehler in Zeile: 8 Spalte: 99
```

It works without the `order by DATETO`

Comment: As you've seen, Oracle doesn't allow using an `order by` clause in a subquery. Can you please share the tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample?

Comment: That ORDER BY makes no sense anyway... What are you trying to solve with it?

Comment: @jarlh it makes sense, that I want to get the latest entry of table mdkndlst

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that rowno. (I'm not an Oracle guy, so I was looking for FETCH FIRST/LIMIT/TOP etc instead.)

Answer (score 2):

In **Oracle 12c**, you can use the new `FETCH FIRST` clause:

```
SELECT
    mdkamvp.mdkamda_sid,
    (SELECT subject
        FROM mdkndlst
        WHERE subject IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY dateto
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) naktion,
    mdkamvp.rowid row_id
FROM springv2.mdkamvp
ORDER BY mdkamvp.indstatus
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `rownum` to a row is done before applying `ORDER BY` clause, so this query

```
SELECT subject
FROM   mdkndlst
WHERE  rownum = 1
       AND subject IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY dateto
```

in fact returns a random row. I believe this is not what you wanted. You probably wanted first to apply `ORDER BY` and then take the first row. That's where subqueries may come in handy:

```
SELECT subject
FROM   (SELECT subject
        FROM   mdkndlst
        WHERE  subject IS NOT NULL
        ORDER  BY dateto)
WHERE  rownum = 1
```

and such query you may now use as a scalar subquery

```
SELECT mdkamvp.mdkamda_sid
      ,(SELECT subject
        FROM   (SELECT subject
                FROM   mdkndlst
                WHERE  subject IS NOT NULL
                ORDER  BY dateto)
        WHERE  rownum = 1) naktion
      ,mdkamvp.rowid row_id
FROM   springv2.mdkamvp
ORDER  BY mdkamvp.indstatus
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use **first_value**

```
SELECT mdkamvp.mdkamda_sid,

  (SELECT DISTINCT first_value(subject) over (partition BY subject
                                              ORDER BY dateto DESC)
   FROM mdkndlst
   WHERE subject IS NOT NULL ) naktion,
       mdkamvp.rowid row_id
FROM springv2.mdkamvp
ORDER BY mdkamvp.indstatus
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a scalar sub-query in the select list, use a derived table where you don't have the limitation with the order by:

```
SELECT MDKAMVP.MDKAMDA_SID, 
       x.subject as NAKTION, 
       MDKAMVP.ROWID ROW_ID 
FROM SPRINGV2.MDKAMVP 
  cross join (
    select SUBJECT 
    from mdkndlst 
    where rownum=1 
      and SUBJECT is not null 
    order by DATETO DESC
  ) x
order by MDKAMVP.INDSTATUS;
```

As the derived table is guaranteed to return exactly one row, the `cross join` will not change the overall result.

If you want the *latest* subject you should also order the DATETO descending. Without that you will get the oldest subject.

If you are using 12c then you might want to use the `fetch first` option as Jiri has shown.